# ractivejs observe init vs set/push/update

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

in this code sample,
on init, observe is fired for each element, even ones without "prices", but does not fire on any other method, **Why?**

```
var _deals = [
    {
        prices: [
            {
                id: 1,
                deal_id: 1,
                guests_from: 100,
                guests_to: 200,
                price: 250
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        prices: []
    },
    {}  // this fires also, Why?
];


var deals = [], // app database
    dealsGuy;   // app instance


deals = _deals;


// create our app view

dealsGuy = new Ractive({
  el: '#app_block',
  template: '#app-template',
  noIntro: true, // disable transitions during initial render

  data: {
    deals: deals
  },

  decorators: {
    datepicker: datepickerDecorator
  }
});   

dealsGuy.observe('deals.*.prices', function (newValue, oldValue, keypath) {

    console.log( 'observe', keypath );

    if( newValue === void 0 || newValue.length <= 0 ){

        this.set(keypath,[{}]);
    }
});

dealsGuy.push('deals', {}); // does not fire 'deals.*.prices'
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your two items in `_deals` are triggered because they contain `prices`, and the one in the end `dealsGuy.push('deals', {});` does not fire because it has no `prices` attribute. Sounds all normal to me. Changing it to `dealsGuy.push('deals', {prices:[]});` should trigger it. Or am I missing something?

Comment: you miss the fact that i said observe is fired for EACH element on init, even ones without "prices".
sorry, but do you speed read? (see edit code sample)

Comment: Hi, being polite won't harm. Since your example didn't contain any item without prices, it wasn't obvious you just speed posted.

Comment: I tired to make a funny =). my example did contain item without prices. I made an edit to put a comment near it. It also looks like a bug to me, may be I'll post it on the repo...

Comment: @Antonimo seems inconsistent to me, probably worthy of a github issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's due to a subbtle difference how things are considered during initialization and updates.

The initialization observe is always triggered (even if the value is `undefined`), while updates are only triggerred if the value actually changes.